# Apache NiFi integration with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, apache-nifi

I have an Apache NiFi server integrated with Active Directory and its working well. But everytime i have to insert a new user into a group in AD, i have to reinitiate my NiFi server for the user to be recognized.  Is there any solution for i don't have to reinitiate my server?

Comment: Would love to know how you got the AD authentication to work.

Comment: Hello, Could please share your experience, i would like to configure Apache NiFi with Active Directory. I tried one time and it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the LdapUserGroupProvider in authorizers.xml, then it should be syncing the users/groups from LDAP into an in-memory cache every 10 seconds.

In newer versions of NiFi there is logging added to the sync:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("-------------------------------------");
                logger.debug("Loaded the following users from LDAP:");
                userList.forEach((user) -> logger.debug(" - " + user));
                logger.debug("--------------------------------------");
                logger.debug("Loaded the following groups from LDAP:");
                groupList.forEach((group) -> logger.debug(" - " + group));
                logger.debug("--------------------------------------");
            }
```

So you should see that output in nifi-app.log if you turn on debug logging for the package *org.apache.nifi.ldap.tenants*